# Randomizing masked choices in Qualtrics with Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, qualtrics

I'm programming a Qualtrics survey in which several different streams of respondents will be presented with different subsets of attributes to rate in a matrix question.

There are quite a number of both attributes and questions, so to avoid spending days clicking through answer-level display logic, I've adapted an answer from @T. Gibbons ([Use Javascript for Qualtrics matrix table display logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111341/use-javascript-for-qualtrics-matrix-table-display-logic?rq=1)) and used Javascript to mask the subsets with the code below.

```
var quest = this.questionId;
var choices = this.getChoices();

var survey_stream = "${e://Field/E8}";
var stream;

var stream1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
var stream2 = ["2", "3", "4", "7", "8", "9"];
var stream3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

if (survey_stream=="1") {stream=stream1;}
if (survey_stream=="2") {stream=stream2;}
if (survey_stream=="3") {stream=stream3;}

var idName;
var hiddenChoices;

hiddenChoices = choices.filter(function(x) {
    return !stream.includes(x);
});

hiddenChoices.each(function(item) {
  idName = "header~"+quest+"~"+item;
  $(idName).up().hide();
});
```

Ideally, the remaining items shown would also be randomized, but selecting the standard randomization option for the question 'breaks' the code above by returning the right number of answer options, but the wrong subset. My guess is that it's randomizing the order of the choices before the masking script runs, so choices are already out of order before the positional references of my streams are applied.

Since I have very limited experience with Javascript and Qualtrics documentation in this area is terrible, are there any suggestions on how I might be able to adapt my code to include the proper randomization of my choice subsets?

Comment: A small update to note for the code, array.includes() is not supported by Internet Explorer so the masking won't work unless you copy/paste the polyfill code found here [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your hiddenChoices.each function try this:

```
hiddenChoices.each(function(item) {
  idName = "QR~"+quest+"~"+item+"~1";
  $(idName).up('tr.ChoiceRow').hide();
});
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. It keeps the right options, even with randomization enabled, but the order stays as-is.

Comment: I don't understand what order you are referring to.  I thought the objective was to randomize and keep the right options.  What else is there?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. If the choices to display are 1, 2, 3 and I change the code like you suggested, along with selecting 'randomize all options', the choices are always displayed in the original order 1, 2, 3 with no randomization.

Comment: The JavaScript just hides the rows, it doesn't move them around. So, the problem is the randomization, not the the script. I just tried the script on randomized matrix and it works fine.

Comment: So strange, I tried it a few times yesterday and had problems, but works fine like you said this morning. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Just so I understand it properly, why does specifying the table row the way you did here work differently than the way I had it originally?

Comment: The ids of the choice (row) labels are just numbered 1, 2, 3, etc. regardless.  The ids of the cells are numbered in the original order. So idName is the id of the first answer cell of the choice you are searching for.  Then up() goes back up the tree to the table row and hides it. On your randomization issue, you probably changed the randomization but never moved off the question before testing, so it wasn't saved.